# Function to approach a number asymptotically

Tags: c++, scaling, allegro5

I have a map that I can zoom in and out of. Gridlines display the latitude and longitude.
Right now I zoom in by shrinking the borders by a specific amount.

Say top edge is lat 30n, bot edge is lat 28n, left edge is lon -40w, right edge is lon -38w.

So for one zoom in, the new edges are 29.5n, 28.5n, -39.5w,-38.5 respectively.

Zooming in enough times would eventually make the opposite edges equal each other and then flip.

So next zoom in for top and bot edge would be 29n, 29n and then next 28.5n,29.5n which flips the orientation.

I'm looking for a function or a way that I can continuously zoom in, but never have the edges equal each other or flip. In others words something where I can get the edges to continuously get closer and closer to each other, but never touch.

So I have an idea that I'll need some function like

`lim x-> infinity of x/(x+1) - 1 + midpoint of the two edges`

which basically means, as I zoom in I will approach the midpoint.
If this is valid, I don't know how to implement limits in C++.

This is only one equation too. I have two edges on each axis and so I'd need two equations to approach the midpoint from both sides at an equal rate.

Comment: Rather than shrinking by a certain amount, maybe shrink by a percentage? Or check the size of the rectangle before you allow another shrink operation - if it's too smaller than the amount you shrink by, then don't allow another shrink...

Comment: @twalberg Yes after seeing the problems I have, I put in a check to make sure the shrink is valid. It's temporary and only gives me resolution up to the static value I shrink by (in this case up to .5 away from each other). A percentage though, that could work! Thanks.

Comment: Never mind. Percentage gives me slightly better resolution, but the edges eventually reach the point where they'll overtake each other.

Comment: Try `left = center - f * (center - left)`, where `f` is factor by which you are zooming (e.g. 2) and center is position that is to be preserved by zooming (e.g. coordinates of mouse pointer or middle of the screen)

Comment: @zch Awesome. This works great for zooming in. As it gets closer to the center, it decreases the amount it zooms in. Now the problem is when I zoom out, as I get further from the center, it gets huge extremely fast.